# Conflicting setter definitions for property

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, jackson

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property &quot;year&quot;: javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar#setYear(1 params) vs javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar#setYear(1 params)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getSetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:293)
springfox.documentation.schema.Annotations.tryGetSetterAnnotation(Annotations.java:74)
springfox.documentation.schema.Annotations.findPropertyAnnotation(Annotations.java:48)
...
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

because I have this mapping in one of my POJOs:

```
@XmlElement(name = "FechaCreacion", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar fechaCreacion;
```

as I have checked *javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar* does have 2 setters for year,

```
public abstract void setYear(BigInteger year);

public abstract void setYear(int year);
```

and is causing the conflict, so, how could I indicate what setter should it use?
Or how to avoid this conflict?

Comment: If one of the setters should be responsible, try setting `@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "year")` to this setter.  Maybe you can take the selection away from Jackson. For JSON there is the annotation @JacksonSetter to determine the setter. For XML, however, there is no such annotation.

Comment: @HansFooBar yes that would do it in any other class, but XMLGregorianCalendar  is a library I cant touch, I change XMLGregorianCalendar  to Date and it worked